# Where is the correct position for "well"?

Tags: adverb-placement, indirect-objects

> I play with my funny cats well. (I suppose this is correct)
>
> I play well with my silly cats. (This is wrong because you should put
>   the adverb of manner after the prepositional indirect object here).

And what about these?

> I play the piano with my stupid and funny cats well.
>
> I play the piano well with my stupid and funny cats (I guess this one is wrong).

I've read that you can't put an adverb between a verb and an object.

Answer (score 2):

> I play with my funny cats well.
>
> I play well with my silly cats.

Both sentences are grammatical. You really *can* put an adverb before a prepositional phrase.

> I play the piano with my stupid and funny cats well

This is stylistically bad. The adverb "well" is placed too far from the verb it modifies. I'd prefer the version that you said was wrong.

You're right that we don't normally put an adverb before an object, but objects are virtually always realized by noun phrases. Prepositional phrases don't function as objects.

Comment: Let me get this straight - "I talked with my funny and silly cats well" is stylistically bad, but "I talked well with my funny and silly cats" is fine, am I right?

Comment: @Rusletov Yes. The latter sentence sounds better and is easier to process.